# Parsing Unstructured Data from BeautifulSoup into Structured Datasets

Tags: python, regex, parsing, data-structures, beautifulsoup

I have a group of 7 files containing unstructured data that I am trying to parse into 7 different datasets in Python that I obtained using beautifulsoup. There are a number of different ways the data is presented and I am struggling to find a proper method through regular expressions or other parsing packages.

I pasted a snippet of data to pastebin: http://pastebin.com/sC9KbhbF

The output data would look like this (I am just using the pipe to separate fields to illustrate, I would want these as separate columns for the output):

```
Street | City | Postal Code  
jln.sidomulyo i-vi | cepu | 58312  
jln.sitimulyo | cepu | 58312  
lr.sitimulyo i-vi | cepu | 58312  
lr.sitimulyo ia-iiia | cepu | 58312  
lr.sitimulyo ib-iiib | cepu | 58312  
lr.sitimulyo ic | cepu | 58312  
lr.sitimulyo iic | cepu | 58312  
jln.sorogo | cepu | 58313  
.....  
jln.akhmad dakhlan kel.ciamis | ciamis | 46211  
jln.akhmad dakhlan kel.linggasari | ciamis | 46216
.....
```

The patterns that make this hard:
1) Putting addresses with commas (e.g. lr. sitimulyo i-vi, ia-iiia) on separate lines keeping the full street name
2) Eliminate whitespace after the period for two letter prefixes (e.g. lr. sitimulyo vs. jln.sidomulyo)
3) Dropping down the street name for nested addresses (e.g. jln.akhmad dakhlan kel.ciamis, jln.akhmad dakhlan kel.linggasari)

I have tried a few different methods but have not even gotten remotely close to far so I did not include those snippets. The code I used to obtain the data is below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re
import bleach
import pandas

url_base = "http://www.indonesianewsonline.com/prangko/stamps"

url_seed = url_base + "/kodepos.htm"

content = urllib2.urlopen(url_seed).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

#print soup.prettify()

additional_links = []

for link in soup.findAll('a', href=True, text=re.compile('Cities*')):
    additional_links.append(link['href'])

links_to_scrape = [url_base + "/" + s for s in additional_links]

data_files = []

for s in links_to_scrape:
    a = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(s).read())
    data_files.append(a.findAll('pre'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it should work: First off you use these regexes and replecments to make the input text more managable:

```
",[ ]*\n[ ]*" replace this with a single comma ","
"\.{2,}" replace this with a single whilte space " "
", " (comma and space) replace it with a single comma ","
"\. " (point a space) replace it with a single point "."
"^[ ]*" any space at the start replace with nothign ""
```

Then you can use this regex

```
"(?<arg1>[^ ]*) (?<arg2>[^ ]*) (?<arg3>[^ ]*) (?<arg4>[0-9]*)[ ]*[\n\r]"
```

If we take the now transformed first line

```
jln.sidomulyo i-vi cepu 58312
```

you get (note arg1 actualy has a new line chart infront so you better check if its present and delete it)

```
arg1:   jln.sidomulyo
arg2:   i-vi
arg3:   cepu
arg4:   58312
```

if we take the lines formated like this

```
lr.sitimulyo i-vi,ia-iiia,ib-iiib,ic,iic cepu 58312
```

you get this (again arg1 has newline on arg1[0] which you need to remove)

```
arg1:   lr.sitimulyo
arg2:   i-vi,ia-iiia,ib-iiib,ic,iic
arg3:   cepu
arg4:   58312
```

Here you will need to itterate through arg2 when you split it up through the "," char and make the entrys like that.

The only problem left are these lines

```
lr.taman siswa i-vii,ia,ib,v/17 cepu 58311
```

Where you have a essentialy 5 whitespaces (or more i guess) and essentialy arg1 needs to everything till this part i assume **"i-vii,ia,ib,v/17"**. There should be a easy solution for this but i couldnt figure it out

Whoops forgot to add lines like this

```
jln.sitimulyo cepu 58312
```

Essentialy dont have a arg4 so you just look out if arg4 is empty or doesnt exists(dont know how it works in python)

GL hope it helped